# Moment.js not giving correct format for GMT date and time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert local time into GMT time in 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM' format. I have tried:

```
moment.utc(new Date(),'YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM').format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM')
```

and also tried

```
 moment().utc().format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM')
```

but for PST time 2017-12-10 17:45 the output is coming 2017-13-10 00:10. The minutes are not coming properly. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You need to use the minutes token for minutes, not the months token.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `M` is short for month, and `m` is short for minute.  Read  [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) more thoroughly.

Comment: Lame, my bad. Thanks though